# Abnormally high network traffic on Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

Using `nload` I see a constant inbound traffic of 2.77MBit/s on my LAN connection.

`nethogs` accounts for only 0.1KB/s of that.

Tried rebooting, without logging in to the GUI, and still the same inbound traffic.

Used `lsof` to see all processes that do something with the FS, and saw none of the programs that I have manually installed.

How can I find what's consuming this traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nethogs` should satisfy your need.

Anyway

This will display programs with network activity

```
sudo netstat -antup | grep ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot replicate the problem any more. At first I thought it was some malware that activated after work hours, because today morning it was absent. It's been 24 hours since I saw it, and it's still quiet.
Since netstat didn't show me any activity either (forgot to mention it), I doubt that this is the answer I was looking for. It is however very useful because it shows the PID, and I could theoretically kill them one by one until the network activity stops, thus identifying it. Anyway, if I don't get evidence of the contrary, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks!